# Score buckets from SED confidence intervals

Tags: confidence-interval, psychometrics

I built an app to illustrate the reliability of standardized tests for a (somewhat) non-technical audience. I'm not a psychometrician, so I want some extra eyes on this to make sure it makes sense.

The idea behind the app is:

- Use the standard error of measurement to determine the standard error of differences using $SED = \sqrt{2 \cdot SEm^2}$
- Determine a 95% (or n%) confidence interval using the SED
- Divide the score range by the width of the confidence interval to determine the number of confidence intervals that can fit into the score range.
- The number of score buckets that a test can sort students into is a useful heuristic for visualizing and thinking about the reliability of the test.

App can be found [here](http://testbuckets.streamlit.app). I've also written a blog post with a bit more background [here](https://medium.com/@steindaavid/lsat-and-gmat-arent-reliable-tests-61a95386802d), intended for a general audience.

Does this score bucket heuristic make sense? If not, why not?

One objection I can think of is that the score buckets aren't equivalence classes (since transitivity fails). But the same could be said of letter grades - those aren't equivalence classes either.

Another objection I can think of is that the score buckets as I've drawn them aren't centered at the difference of two scores, they're centered at one score. But this really shouldn't matter. To see why, let $w$ be the half-width of a score bucket, $w:=t_{\alpha/2,n-1}  \cdot SED $, and let $x$ and $y$ be two scores. Then,
$|x-y| < w \implies -w < x-y < w \implies y-w < x < y + w $.

Am I missing something? It's pretty surprising how bad some of the standardized tests (GMAT and LSAT in particular) look in this light.

(Edit: I am aware that an even better approach might use $SE_{est}$, or the standard error at a given ability level. But I'm not sure that I can calculate that without actual student responses, and I'm trying to keep things simple for now)